# Creating a 'partial' patch file / Using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch

We're using TortoiseSVN to create patches for code review.

We're running into the scenario that a patch is out for review and then some further work is done on the same files. Is it possible to create a "differential" file between the earlier one and the new one, so that the "combined code" is not reviewed - only what has changed from the first patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TortoiseSVN documentation on creating patches it says

> You can produce separate patches containing changes to different sets of files. Of course, if you create
>   a patch file, make some more changes to the same files and then create another patch, the second patch
>   file will include both sets of change

So it makes no mention of creating a patch of a patch. What you could do is create the first patch and then create the second patch (which will contain all the changes) and do a diff on the two using something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Perhaps it is worth asking yourself if this is the best approach? You may want to view all the changes as a whole for the code review.